# What does the sentence and ‘’active’ mean in this case?

Tags: word-meaning, sentence-meaning

> He basically looks like Auguste Rodin’s The Thinker, if the sculpture was smoking a spliff and wearing tan Tabis. I write that with the implied smirk I believe Healy would approve of. He’s a man who lives the impossible task of balancing extensive use of cultural references and self-awareness; a man who has a first edition of Infinite Jest with a bookmark placed a quarter of the way through for display in the next room, partly because he’s a David Foster Wallace fan but mostly as a nod to that joke about everyone having a copy of it a quarter-read. A man — white, straight — whose willingness to talk about art and ideas has sometimes been viewed, in our postmodern, nihilistic and hyper-consumptive era, as pretentious. He thinks his brain works fast rather than well but he’s sharp enough to be the person who captured what people think of him best in a 2016 Rolling Stone interview: “quite obnoxious but quite sincere.”

> This introduction should be read as playful, not only because Healy is funny and likeable, but because he explicitly told me not to write that he’s taking dramatic pauses. **In fairness, they’re not dramatic so much as they are active.** This is the first time he’s speaking about his forthcoming album to a person outside his inner circle, someone who is here to professionally question him after he said in 2020 that he was doing his last interviews. “I don’t like it that much because it’s so scary,” he explains of the process. “I think I’d gotten to a point where I didn’t know how much I wanted to qualify my statements.”

Source(https://www.rollingstone.co.uk/music/features/the-1975-being-funny-in-a-foreign-language-new-album-interview-19940/)

“**In fairness, they’re not dramatic so much as they are active.**”

I’d like to know what the above sentence in bold and ‘active’ mean in this case. My interpretation is that he’s taking dramatic pauses while talking, which may make him sound pretentious so he doesn’t want the readers to know that, but the interviewer thinks it rather makes the conversation active (lively). One of the confusing parts to me is the ‘active’. I understand what active means, but I don’t really get what the interviewer is trying to say by it. Does it mean lively in this case?
I’d greatly appreciate any help from native speakers.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The term "active pause" doesn't mean anything to me. My guess is it means while Healy was paused in speaking, his body was still somehow animated, like he was thinking hard or excited or something. The rest of your interpretation sounds exactly right

Comment: Thank you so much for the interpretation. I think that more makes sense.